# Do carry capacity modifiers work on companions?

Tags: fallout-4

I've read that Preston has a carry weight of 165lbs. If I equip him with modified items (such as pocketed armour pieces), will it increase his carry capacity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions) wiki page (toward the bottom of the page) companions are affected by pocketed armor.

> It is possible to make companions wear pocketed armor to increase their max weight (+30 pounds with basic pockets). There is also a skill magazine perk that will increase the companion carry weight by 10.

Answer (score 3):

A companion will profit from any equipment as well as you do. This includes carry weight, S.P.E.C.I.A.L Attributes or the effects of legendary gear.

Comment: This is actually not entirely accurate.  I gave Nick a Legendary laser rifle with unlimited ammo, and he's using up the fusion cores I gave him, so at least some of them don't work properly

Comment: @Taegost Hm didn't know that. I gave piper general chaos blade and she's totally wrecking any kind of robots

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty disappointed that it didn't work, but I don't use laser weapons at all and that one is pretty nice so it's not a big deal at the moment

Comment: @Taegost / YUNOWORK - Here is a pic of Cait [lighting up a Bloodbug with an Incendiary Pipe Pistol](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZaeN.jpg). Companions can definitely utilise legendary mods. (Feel free to use the image in your answer if you want YUNOWORK) :)

Comment: @Robotnik - That's why I ended with "at least some of them don't work properly".  I know for a fact that Unlimited Ammo on a laser rifle isn't working in Valentine's hands in my game.

Comment: @Taegost There is no "unlimited ammo" [legendary modifier](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects). There is "unlimited magazine size". It means you never have to reload (ammo capacity is equal to ammo carried), it doesn't mean you never run out of ammo.

Comment: @T.J.L. - Mine clearly says "Never runs out of ammo" or something to that effect...  I assume that it means it doesn't use up ammo since it's not made clear in game

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think SPECIAL attributes remain unaffected. I equipped Cait with the Grognak costume, which is supposed to increase STRENGTH by 2. But her Carry weight did not increase. 
Don't know about pocketed armor, though.

Edit: As other have pointed out in the meantime, it actually does affect carry weight! But one has to get out of the trade-menu and re-enter for the effect to kick in. My bad!

Comment: Hmm, maybe i missed something, but I'm quite sure that it does. I'll try it once I'm home.

Comment: @YUNOWORK It does, see the tests I ran here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246913/28182

Answer (score -1):

Weapons with the Unlimited Ammo perk still consume ammo.  The perk just means you never have to reload the magazine.  Say you have a combat rifle with a large quick eject magazine that hold 40 rounds.  With the unlimited ammo perk, you never have to reload the magazine after 40 rounds.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.