# Do companions have S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats?

Tags: fallout-4

More specifically, are companions affected by buffs to S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats, such as a +1 STR from equipped gear? Are there any stats more useful to buff than others, for certain characters?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Do companions have S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats?

**Yes**, they do have S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats.

You can work out a companion's stats on PC by opening the console, clicking on the companion or other entity (Bethesda refers to them as 'actors') and utilising the console command `getav <stat>`

For example:

[image: Cait in Fallout 4]

I also performed `player.getav Strength` so I could compare the stats and ensure that I was in fact getting Cait's stat, not my own.

[image: Cropped to just show the stats]

As you can see, my own personal Strength stat is 7, whilst Cait's is 5.

Companion Carry Weight is a calculated value that can also be checked. Cait again as our test example, has 150, whilst I currently have 350:

[image: Cait's vs My carry weight]

---

> Do companions benefit from S.P.E.C.I.A.L. increases?

Let's find out! We can use `setav <stat> <value>` to set the S.P.E.C.I.A.L. stats to whatever we want:

[image: Cait's Strength modified to be 10]

By setting Cait's Strength to 10, we can see that this also raises her Carry Weight to 200.

---

> Do companions benefit from S.P.E.C.I.A.L. bonuses from equipped items?

**Yes**!, take Army Fatigues for example, which provide +1 Strength when equipped:

[image: Cait with Army Fatigues]

I've removed everything else from Cait's inventory for this test to avoid any other equipment messing with the stats. I ran the `getav` command for Strength and Carry Weight before and after equipping the Fatigues:

[image: getav Strength/CarryWeight]

As you can see, Cait's Stats raise from 5 Strength, 150 CarryWeight to 6 Strength, 160 CarryWeight:

[image: getav Strength/CarryWeight zoomed in]

---

> Are there any stats more useful to buff than others, for certain characters?

- Strength for Carry Weight is probably the biggest one.
- Endurance does not seem to have an effect on health (I ran `resethealth` in case it had set the maximum but not the current health):

[image: Endurance tests]

Comment: BAM, I knew it. Awesome answer by the way. You have my upvote.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Thanks! - I'm still mulling over how to test other stats - I have a feeling that Agility affects their Sneak and Perception affects their ability to sense/spot enemies, but that will require a lot of testing :)

Comment: I'm curious if the effects of legendary equipment affect them. When i gave cait the sword which deals 50% bonus dmg to robots, she was completely melthing through those synths in arc-jet. But a lot of people say this is not true, which leaves me thinking. Also no idea how to directly test that.

Comment: @YUNOWORK - Hmm interesting point. We could probably spawn a particular Legendary Weapon for testing, and the same weapon without the Legendary bonus to compare the two. Firing speed buffs is probably the easiest to test (here's hoping there's a legendary effect that affects that :)

Comment: @YUNOWORK Ooh, they do, I just tested it out. I gave Cait a Pipe Pistol with the Incendiary mod vs a Bloodbug. Lit it up like a Christmas tree haha :)

Comment: Great, so I'm not mistaken. I was so sure, the dmg cait dealt was just dumb. And i play on survival. But thanks for proofing my theory :P

Comment: @YUNOWORK - anytime :)

Comment: Thanks for the enthusiastic comments and answer guys, great testing

Comment: The END boost on shirts doesn't even affect the player character's HP.  I boost my END via a hat and that increased my HP, but not the END from my shirt or other legendary END boosting armor... it's kind of weird.

Comment: you can also use setav to SET the companions value and 10 isn't the limit! you can' set them all to 999 and your companion will 1 hit kill anything

Answer (score -3):

I don't think they have SPECIAL attributes simply because they would not matter (except strength and endurance).

STR = plus in carry weight and melee damage (yes that works)
PER = accuracy in VATS (I don't think companions use VATS)
END = health increase (seems to work as well)
CHR = persuasion in dialogues (companions don't need it)
INT = experience point gain (companions don't need it)
AGI = action points (companions don't use AP)
LCK = criticals in VATS (again, no VATS for companions)

Comment: This is a good point about most of these stats not mattering, but that doesn't mean they don't have them. They do.