# How does S.P.E.C.I.A.L affect settlers in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I can give special raising gear to my settlers and companions and it increases their stats but I have no idea if it gives them any useful benefits.

I know Strength increases companions carry weight and (hopefully) raises their melee damage.

But what about Agility or Perception? Do they have any effect on weapon accuracy if npcs don't have access to vats and don't use action points (melee settlers probably use action points for power attacks similar to Skyrim).

Comment: For the companion portion of the question, check out [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246870/do-companions-have-s-p-e-c-i-a-l-stats). I think the 'settlers' portion makes this question NOT a duplicate, maybe you should focus on that part in your question.

Comment: Changed npc to settlers in topic title

Comment: Give them more defense and higher firepower. Ignore stats. If there are stats on gear.. just ignore them.

Comment: I asked the question linked in the first comment and I can't believe this question never occurred to me. +1

Comment: Heck, I had such thoughts, too. Then I just ignored the Minutemen and their constant nagging for attention altogether. I suppose the settlers benefit from Strength and Endurance only.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and can now answer your question. Strength does raise damage, Agility increases attack speed and defence, And perception raises accuracy. Yes they have an effect on accuracy if they don't have access to vats and don't use action points.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what research you did?

Comment: I second that - could you post your full research data and methodology?